# Excel Chart Timeline

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-excel-2011

I have a CSV file that I have opened in Excel 2011 for Mac.

The CSV looked like this:

```
  Timestamp           |    URL
01/Jan/2014:01:01:01   /path/to/something1
01/Jan/2014:01:01:05   /path/to/something2
01/Jan/2014:01:01:15  /path/to/something1
01/Jan/2014:01:01:45   /path/to/something2
```

I'd like to make a timechart that looks like:

```
     |
     |                            *
     |
     |           *
URL #|      *        *                  *
     |  *                 *
     |
     |
     |___________________________________________
                   (Time/Dates)
```

Can anyone point me to a tutorial that can help me here, or provide me any guidance as to what to look for?

Answer (score 0):

With the file open in Excel, create a pivot table. Drag the time stamp into the Rows area, the URL into the Columns area, and again into the Values area.

Then create a pivot chart, set it to be a line chart. Format the lines to have markers and no line. Make sure the X axis is a date axis.

This works in Excel for Windows. Not 100% sure if there are differences for these aspects in Excel 2011 for Mac.